# Switch AutoDesk Forge Viewer Environment from Local to AutodeskProduction

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

We are using autodesk-forge viewer to show 3D Models, We have a requirement as to load the models from the **local environment** and the **auto desk cloud environment**

Previously we are using only **local environment**, Viewer initialized with the **"env":"Local"**

```
let initOptions = {
  'env': 'Local'
  'language': 'en'
}

Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(initOptions)
```

Now we need to switch between the **Local Environment** and **AutodeskProduction**, is that Possible?

To achieve switching, what cloud i have to do.

Have to re-Initialize the Viewer with new env?

Please help me...

Answer (score 1):

Simply terminate/finish the previous/existing Viewer and re-initialize as you normally would all over again:

```
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer( {'env' : 'Local', getAccessToken: 
  //...
}, () =>{
   // viewer = ...

  })             
})

//...

viewer.finish()


Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer( {'env' : 'AutodeskProduction', getAccessToken: 
  //...
}, () =>{
   // viewer = ...

  })             
})
```

Comment: let me do a trail

Comment: No, It is not working as expected, getting error as Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localendpoint/CampusVianen/Resource/as.svf' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status

Comment: Working, Thank you Bryan