# How do I load the bubble.json from aws s3 bucket

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

Following adams blog post for speeding up viewables generated from design automation for inventor, instead of storing the resulting files on a forge bucket, i would like to store them on my aws s3 bucket. I am redirecting to the aws bucket bubble.json but im getting a console error after the redirect saying "Cannot read property 'traverse' of undefined" which leads me to believe that the bubble.json is not being loaded correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide more info on how you are redirecting? Is it a public S3 bucket? Are you redirecting to a pre-signed URL?

Comment: I tried the following: redirect to the aws presigned url, redirect to the public url after making the file public, and loading the file in the front end with the public url

Comment: Can you please check that the content of the bubble.json looks OK? Also, on the network tab of the bowser's developer tools can you check if it can reach the other files as well, like result.svf, 0.pf, etc?

Comment: i believe the bubble.json looks fine although im not sure what would not look fine. when doing the redirect no other files are trying to be loaded

Comment: @AdamNagy i believe the issue is that when doing the load of the bubble.json, the function is trying to pass in an Authorization token. Any way around this?

Comment: Call `Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer()` with option "env": "Local" - like e.g. done in the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62234001/switch-autodesk-forge-viewer-environment-from-local-to-autodeskproduction

Comment: @AdamNagy with that change it is working. Thanks for your help